# how to set marquee on CustomActionBar theme?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles, marquee, android-titlebar

I need to set text moving or scrolling text from right to left i.e how can i use marquee effect on my CustomActionBar theme in android. Show can i do changes in the same. I have been attach java and xml and style files. Need help

How can i use it?

```
**style.xml**

    <resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.



    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.



        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">#F05B30</item>
    </style>

    <style name="fontForNotificationLandingPage">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">NotoSerif-Regular</item>
    </style>

</resources>

**New_details.java**

    package com.example.ourvadodara;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static com.example.ourvadodara.News.KEY_TITLE;
import static com.example.ourvadodara.News.KEY_Details;
import static com.example.ourvadodara.News.KEY_THUMB_URL;

public class News_details extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news_details);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        // Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)
        // getIntent().getParcelableExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL);
        // Bitmap bMapScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,350, 150, true);
        String title = "";
        String details = "";
        String path = "";

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (null != intent) {
            title = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_TITLE);
            details = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_Details);
            path = intent.getStringExtra("img_url");
        }

        imageLoader il = new imageLoader(this);
        il.DisplayImage(path, (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgdetails));
        Log.i("bitmap", "null");

        TextView headlineTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.headlines);
        headlineTxt.setText(title);
        getActionBar().setTitle(title);

        TextView descriptionTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
        descriptionTxt.setText(details);

    }
}

**activity_news_details.xml**

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#E6E6E6" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#E6E6E6" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgdetails"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/headlines"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/headlines"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imgdetails"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="23sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
             android:ellipsize="marquee"
             android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
// make the title scroll!
// find the title TextView

TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.title);
// set the ellipsize mode to MARQUEE and make it scroll only once
title.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
title.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(1);
// in order to start strolling, it has to be focusable and focused
title.setFocusable(true);
title.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
title.requestFocus();
```

Comment: android.R.id.title see this

Comment: its is used to title by default id